# ¿Cómo puede decirse "To cc someone on an email"?

Tags: traducción, correspondencia, email

¿Cuál sería la forma más idiomática de expresar la siguienta frase inglesa?

> I will cc you on the email.

Hay muchas palabras de la informática o los negocios donde se utilizan palabras inglesas directamente como *marketing* o el propio *email*, pero *cc* me suena muy raro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo uso:

> te copio en el mail.

Si es bcc:

> te agrego en copia oculta.

Answer (score 3):

Lo cierto es que yo *incluyo* a la gente en mis emails o *les pongo en copia*, pero siempre que uso esas frases, quiero decir que van recibir el email, no que específicamente vayan en la línea de CC. Sin embargo, al incluir a alguien el copia **oculta** queda muy claro que ese destinatario va en *CCO*.

En un ambiente de negocios puede ser importante la distinción de porqué te llega el correo (si estás directamente involucrado en algo, o más bien sólo necesitas estar al tanto o supervisar). Dicho eso, muchas de las interfaces de email en nuestro idioma tienen todos los vocablos en castellano, menos ese *carbon copy*, y esa función no es más que otro *añadir destinatario* cuando pasas el puntero sobre ella, o si consultas la ayuda del sistema. Alguna vez que he querido enfatizar eso, he dicho que alguien *iba en cc*, tirando de anglicanismo.

> Juan Lopez estaba **copiado** en mi correo sobre lo de la impresora, porque con estas cosas **incluyo en copia** a todo el equipo. Al jefe de proyecto **le puse también en CC**, para que se entere del problema el día que revise sus emails y para quede constancia, pero al de departamento le **puse en copia oculta**, para que vea lo que hay sin que se enteren los otros de que lo sabe, y que hagan lo que hacen siempre...

Comment: Habrá que verbalizarlo como en inglés.  *CCear* o *ceceear* :)

Comment: @guifa pero cecear ya es una palabra D:

Answer (score 2):

Yo usaría el verbo *incluir*, o si es necesario ser muy preciso, *incluir con copia*

Answer (score 2):

*CC* significa "carbon copy" en inglés y "[con copia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copia_de_carb%C3%B3n)" en español. No hace falta traducirlo si no se quiere porque las siglas coinciden. Por tanto, puedes decir:

> Te lo mando con copia para Álvaro.

En el caso de BCC, "blind carbon copy", yo uso "con copia oculta", CCO si te atreves a usar las siglas.

> Hoy escribo al inspector, con copia oculta para ti.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre he usado *Te pongo en copia* o *Te pongo en Cc*, y nunca alguna de las otras propuestas. Sin embargo, es muy casual y no se tendría que usar con clientes, proveedores, etc... pero más bien con compañeros de trabajo o amigos.